# Constant subsequence from given sequence of numbers in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, sequence

Hi I want to get a subsequence of the same numbers from given sequence.
The subsequences should be returned as list.

For example

```
input = [4, 5, 67, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 3]
```

and

```
output = [ [4, 4, 4], [2, 2] ].
```

I have a problem with for loop because when I compare two elements of list e.g:

```
for i in seq:
       if i == seq[i+1]
```

I'm getting a list index out of range error.
I know it isn't complicated but I'm just getting started with programming.

Comment: `for i in seq[:-1]` will solve your problem

Comment: @SalvadorDali not, it doesnt, If array has one element ? seq[i-1] will return an empty list.

Comment: @levi and what kind of the **same numbers** can you get from a list of **only one number**?

Answer (score 1):

When your loop reaches the last element in the array, in your example `3`, you are trying to get the "next element" `seq[i+1]` but there is no one, because 3 is the last one.

So, you can try to check if there is a next element.

```
for i in seq:
       next = seq[i+1] if i < len(seq) else None
       if next and i ==  next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby of itertools here

```
import itertools

input = [4, 5, 67, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 3]
list_of_sequence_list = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(input)]
subsequence_list = [sequence_list for sequence_list in list_of_sequence_list if len(sequence_list)>1]

print subsequence_list
```